# Visual Studio Code - C++ Debugger doesn't start

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, mono

I've been using Visual Studio Code to debug C++ on Linux for a while now.

In a sample project I've got the following `launch.json`:

```
{
    "name": "(gdb) Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I've successfully compiled and run main.c, so debugging should work fine.

When I start the debugger, a blue loading bar appears under the arrow and nothing happens. On my laptop, with the exact same configuration, the loading bar would disappear after a couple of seconds and the debugger would start.

Looking at `ps aux` I can see two new processes:

1. `mono.linux-x86_640` with the command `/home/guyyst/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.20.1/debugAdapters/mono.linux-x86_64 --config /home/guyyst/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.20.1/debugAdapters/framework/config.linux /home/guyyst/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.20.1/debugAdapters/bin/OpenDebugAD7.exe`
2. `bash` with the command `bash /home/guyyst/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.20.1/debugAdapters/OpenDebugAD7`

Debugging on my laptop spawns the same processes, but they disappear when the debugging actually starts. The two processes on my PC stick around even after closing VSCode. When I first noticed this I had 15+ copies running from previous attempts.

All of this worked fine yesterday, and I don't remember making any changes to my configuration since then.

I've tried reinstalling VSCode several times through either the AUR version `visual-studio-code-bin` or the open source package `code`.

Debugging some Python code worked just fine.

Comment: Don't use anything else than *just* the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) in a terminal, on a command line. Compile your C++ code on the command line, with all warnings and debug info (so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (you don't need visual-studio-code for that)

Comment: Support for C++ development in VS code is very basic. It would be a better idea to use something else, like normal Visual Studio or Eclipse CDT.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Obviously I don't _need_ VSCode to debug C++, but with larger programs and more complicated code I'm gonna pick a GUI over doing everything in a terminal any day.

Comment: I was able to debug GCC (which has many millions lines of code) with `gdb` on the command line. So it can debug quite large programs (and Linux has no other debugger today, except [lldb](https://lldb.llvm.org/)..). BTW, you could also use `gdb` in [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). So learn to use `gdb` in a terminal, and later, when you are familiar with that, consider using VSCode

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Some people are able to run marathon but it is not a convenient way to get around.

Comment: `gdb` is quite simple to use, and do not require other things. I really recommend using `gdb` by itself. If your goal is to debug your program, do it simply, by using `gdb` on the command line (as [documented](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) in the documentation of `gdb`). If your goal is to learn configuration of VSCode, dive into [documentation of VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs) (which I feel is like a marathon). Why use some complex combination of tools when using a plain tool (`gdb` alone) is enough?

Comment: try to add the path of **gdb** to your launcher.json like I have done:
`"miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe"` if you need i can post you my whole launcher.json but I am using it on windows

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out it was as easy as setting `externalConsole` in `launch.json` to `false`. Should've probably thought of trying that before.

I'm constrained to the VSCode console, which isn't that big a deal.

I still can't explain why it won't work with an external console, since that's how I'm still doing it on my laptop and used to do it on my PC too.

Comment: This fixed it for me too. I had also been using VS Code to debug C++ successfully on Linux for months, and it stopped working today. Changing `externalConsole` from `true` to `false` made it work again.

Comment: This worked for me too, but when I try to add arguments to the args property it does not stop at the break points. When I remove the args it stops at the break points once again

Comment: `externalConsole = true` stopped working for me today, debugging C++ on ubuntu.  I guess we should file a bug somewhere?