# How to read input when debugging in C++ in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm using **VSCode** for debugging my **CPP** program in **MacOSX**.

I've 2 programs.

**Program1**

```
int main(){

    string a;
    a = "a";
    a += 'b';
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Program2**

```
int main(){

    string a;
    cin>>a;
    a += 'b'
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

In **program1** I'm directly assigning the `string a` and when I debug the program in `VSCode` by first compiling it in terminal using :

`g++ -g filename.cpp`

and then selecting the **Starting Debugging** option in the **Debugging menu**. I'm able to see the state of the `string a` variable by moving forward in breakpoints.

The **VARIABLES** section shows the state of different variables and the **CALL STACK** show the stack frame.

But, for **program2**, when I go past the breakpoint of the `cin>>a;`, the contents of **VARIABLES** and of **CALL STACK** get cleared up.

Here are the contents of the `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [    
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get user-input and move forward to debug my code?

Comment: Not sure if it is the same for VSCode but in VS when you step over input in the debugger you can switch over to the console window and type in the input, press enter, and then go back to stepping through the code.

Comment: @Jos Place a breekpoint to this statement a += 'b'

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, I did that and the debugging pauses there. Where can I provide my inputs?

Comment: @Jos Use the console window.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Is that the same as `Terminal` OR `Debug Console`? I mean, where is that present?

Comment: @Jos I did not use this IDE. Try to use Terminal.

Comment: Do I need to run my program? I guess so. Nope running doesn't help.

Comment: The terminal just shows the command that I had executed before debugging ie - `Ajays-Air:cppnew ajay$ g++ -g d.cpp`

Comment: Where is the location/window/panel that shows the output of `cout<<a`?

Comment: @rioV8 The output is shown in the `Debug console`.

Comment: That should be the location where to enter the program keyboard input

Comment: @rioV8 Unfortunately, that's NOT.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As stated in [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/449)

> if you enable **"externalConsole":true** in the **launch.json** then you will get a pop up console window that you can type in.

Comment: This does not seem to work with piping input from stdin like `./program < input.txt`. Is there an alternative for that?

Comment: Turns out that it works if you put "<" and "input.txt" as separate arguments.

Comment: sadly this isn't an option for me. the debugger never launches. same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108690/visual-studio-code-c-debugger-doesnt-start

Comment: This is outdated information. I just installed Mac CodeLLDB and it is now a little easier, but there are still a few steps. Watch a video walk-through this worked for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKjFVyDbSpA

Comment: I don't know when they update that, but now to get the same result the configuration is :
`"console": "integratedTerminal"`

Answer (score 10):

To debug with inputs, you can edit the arg section as shown below:

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/main",
"args": ["<", "input_file.in"]
```

The example above should be the same as: `./main < input_file.in`

Answer (score 6):

1. Install extension [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb)
2. Add new configuration `CodeLLDB: Launch`

   [image: Add new configuration]
3. Set `program` property as `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"`
4. (optional) Rebuild code
5. Chose created `Launch` config in VS Debug tab. And start it!

   [image: Chose created Launch config in VS Debug tab]

Profit!
[image: Demo]
[Video manual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKjFVyDbSpA)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps anyone who comes around here:

by (1) setting "externalConsole" to `true` and (2) checking (enabling) "Run In Terminal" in Code-Runner Extension configuration, you can plug-in your input to your code by typing the input on the external console, that would pop up when you run your code.

Answer (score 1):

simply:-
step1. click on small gear-icon of debugger window.
step2. make "true" to this ["externalConsole": false,] in launch.json file.
step3. and just restart your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, my solution was to replace cygwin's gdb and g ++ with mingw64's.

Comment: Can you please explain what settings you have done?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was a two-step process.

1. Enable externalConsole: true, as described in other responses.
2. [Let VS code control the terminal.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5079#issuecomment-626090192)

Answer (score 0):

If the code you are debugging requires user input, **set external Console to true**. after entering input, **avoid clicking "x" to close the external Console**. Instead, **click "-" to minimise the window**. Then keep hitting f10 or f11 to continue debugging.

Comment: I tried this, What my VS code does is, it opens entirely new terminal instance ( rather using VS-code terminal , which opens in bottom part ) . I was able to do debugging, but lot of switching between windows. Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: There is no need to switch windows. Simply divide the computer screen in half, keeping the VS code and the debugging window on either side. And keep debugging

Answer (score 0):

externalConsole: true,
allows me to type input in the external console
but the redirection method "args":["<","in.txt"],
does NOT

Using:
VSCode 1.80.2 with C/C++ Extension from Microsoft v1.16.3 and Clang
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix

macOS: Ventura 13.5 (22G74)