# Terminal not working while debugging C programs

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have a problem where whenever I debug a C program my terminal does not accept input, or scanf in this case. Everything else seems to be working, the debugger prints out everything and stops at breakpoint. When I start the program without debugging I can write to the terminal. Please help

Thank you

[image][image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you add `-g` to the compiler flags? It adds debugging symbols.

Comment: Can you explain how I do that? Sorry I am not good at this.

Comment: Is it in the tasks.json?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There are many pitfalls with using scanf and one of them might only be visible while debugging.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    scanf("%i", &c);
    printf("%i", c);
}

`

Comment: I only have this

Comment: You need to provide us more details.

Comment: `gcc -g -Wall -o (outputname) (source-file.c)`

Comment: I added some pictures

Comment: gcc -g -Wall -o (outputname) (source-file.c). Do I put this in a terminal?

Comment: You need any more information?

Comment: You might need to add the flag "-g" to your tasks.json : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57173879/11774715

Comment: It is already there, check the first picture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read input when debugging in C++ in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494832/how-to-read-input-when-debugging-in-c-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Nope, this only shows how to use a external cmd prompt which I don't want.

Comment: @ErayZaxy `gcc -g -Wall -o (outputname) (source-file.c)`  put it in terminal, and run with `gdb ./outputname`

Comment: outputname : The term 'outputname' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.